# Clone SQLDataReader to get number of rows

Tags: c#, list, clone, sqldatareader

I have a datareader.  I need to find the number of rows in it so that I can instantiate an array. Initially I did this by using:

```
<code>
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
int noOfRows = dt.Rows.Count; 
</code>
```

However I found that loading the reader into the datatable will close the reader before I am able to iterate through it later in my code.  I was thinking of cloning the reader and passing the clone to the Datatable.  Is this possible or advisable?

Is there a better way of finding the number of rows in my data reader?  I know I could do something with a list (not fully sure what) but my datareader contains 33 fields of varying data types and I dont know how to put that all into a list.

thanks

Comment: No it is just a one off query.  The project is really small.  The query is a basic SELECT tablexxx FROM WHERE.
Can i use the SET NOCOUNT ON on this?  SQL isnt really my thing.

Comment: You could just use your DataTable now that it is full.

Comment: Once you have loaded the DataTable with the reader you don't need anymore the reader. Just use the DataTable Rows, all data is there.

Comment: If I am using the following to run through my datareader how would I change this to be the datatable.

    <code>
    while (reader.Read() && (i != noOfRows))
    </code>

In other words how do i loop a datatable?

Comment: Ill do it as foreach loop

Comment: You could loop through table using `foreach(DataRow drow in DataTable.Rows) {}`

Comment: I used the DataTable and looped through it.  All seems to be good.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Neither ADO.NET nor SQL Server itself knows the number of rows before they have been sent. You can only find out by enumerating all rows.

Maybe you can just use a `List` instead of an array so that you don't have to pre-define the size?